# Josephus algorithm partial succes

Tags: python, algorithm, josephus

My friend told me about [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), where you have `41` people sitting in the circle. Person number `1` has a sword, kills person on the right and passes the sword to the next person. This goes on until there is only one person left alive. I came up with this solution in python:

```
print('''There are n people in the circle. You give the knife to one of 
       them, he stabs person on the right and
       gives the knife to the next person. What will be the number of whoever
       will be left alive?''')

pplList = []
numOfPeople = int(input('How many people are there in the circle?'))


for i in range(1, (numOfPeople + 1)):
    pplList.append(i)
print(pplList)

while len(pplList) > 1:
    for i in pplList:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            del pplList[::i]
    print(f'The number of person which survived is {pplList[0]+1}')
    break
```

But it only works up to `42` people. What should I do, or how should I change the code so it would work for, for example, `100, 1000` and more people in the circle?

I've looked up Josephus problem and seen different solutions but I'm curious if my answer could be correct after some minor adjustment or should I start from scratch.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: What do you mean by it only works up to 42 people? What's the error when you try 43 or more?

Comment: then the answer is wrong. I can't figure out how to write the condition for i % 2 != 0

Comment: If you click on the Josephus tag, you'll see all the question with that tag. You'll find many different ways of solving this problem (and the related problem where you don't just want to know who survives, but want the list of victims in the order they were killed).

Answer (score 1):

I see two serious bugs.

1. I guarantee that `del ppList[::i]` does nothing resembling what you hope it does.
2. When you wrap around the circle, it is important to know if you killed the last person in the list (first in list kills again) or didn't (first person in list dies).

And contrary to your assertion that it works up to 42, it does not work for many smaller numbers.  The first that it doesn't work for is 2.  (It gives 3 as an answer instead of 1.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. What do you mean by 1.? Should it be 'del pplList[:i]' or something else? How about the changing index of numbers when the first iteration ends? How could I change the condition right there? I don't know if this is clear what I say.

Comment: @piotrulu The usual process that lead to bizarre operations like that is, "I am looking for a syntax that does the magic operation in my head."  Your reply "Should it be..." is a continuation of that.  Instead describe your magic operation, and break it up into code that you can write.  It doesn't matter whether you need 1 line or 10 in the end, break down what you are thinking into simpler components.

Comment: As for what it actually does.  Suppose that on the second run you see a 3 in slot 2.  Then you'll start at the beginning and delete every third, so you remove people from slots 0, 3, 6, 9, 12...  (Remember, arrays start at slot 0.)

Comment: I'm afraid that I lack the proper syntax in my Python dictionary if I may phraze it that way. I'm overthinking the problem, making it impossible in my head, while in reality it probably is as simple as it can be. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction? For example, if the method I chose, with lists, is right for this task? Or is the `del pplList[::i]` the only one you would change?
EDIT: oh, I posted after your second comment

Comment: @piotrulu I can make the program work in a million ways.  That won't help you. 
 What will is breaking it down into small, clear, pieces.  Be very, very clear on what should happen.  Put debugging statements in to make sure that that, and only that is happening.  Repeat this process until your small, clear, pieces are Python functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not considering the guy in the end if he is not killed. Example, if there are 9 people, after killing 8, 9 has the sword, but you are just starting with 1, instead of 9 in the next loop. As someone mentioned already, it is not working for smaller numbers also. Actually if you look close, you're killing odd numbers in the very first loop, instead of even numbers. which is very wrong.

You can correct your code as followed

```py
while len(pplList )>1:
    if len(pplList )%2 == 0:
        pplList  = pplList [::2] #omitting every second number
    elif len(pplList )%2 ==1:
        last = pplList [-1] #last one won't be killed
        pplList  = pplList [:-2:2]
        pplList .insert(0,last) # adding the last to the start
```

There are very effective methods to solve the problem other than this method. check [this link](https://medium.com/@sudheernaidu53/the-josephus-problem-36cbf94f3a64) to know more